# How to return multiple Mongodb Collections in one app.get request?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I need to load two sets of data from two different mongodb collections onto one page.
My route page that makes the request through mongoose looks like this

```
app.get('/testPage', function(req,res){
    dbReadOne.find({}, '', function(error, dataOne){
        res.json(dataOne);
    });
    dbReadTwo.find({},'', function(error, dataTwo){
        res.json(dataTwo);
    });
});
```

My Angular factories look like this

```
app.factory('dataOneFactory', function($resource){
    return $resource('testPage/:dataOne', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', params:  {symbol: 'dataOne'}, isArray: true}
    })
});
app.factory('dataTwoFactory', function($resource){
    return $resource('testPage/:dataTwo', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', params:  {customList: 'dataTwo'}, isArray: true}
    })
});
```

I'm completely lost on how to do this.  I'd appreciate any advice I can get on this issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since Node.js is asynchronous in nature, *dbReadOne.find* function runs asynchronously, therefore you should call the next *dbReadOne.find* in the callback of first *dbReadOne.find* function.

Example:

```
app.get('/testPage', function(req, res){
     dbReadOne.find({}, '', function(errorOne, dataOne){
         if(errorOne)
            throw new Error(errorOne);
         dbReadTwo.find({},'', function(errorTwo, dataTwo){
            if(errorTwo)
                throw new Error(errorTwo);
            res.json({
                dataOne: dataOne,
                dataTwo: dataTwo
            });
         });
     });
});
```

Comment: These don't rely on each other. Promise.all should be used instead

Comment: If they don't rely on each other why would we want to use **Promise.all** and wait for every thing to resolve/reject ?

Comment: If there is an error the request **should** fail. Your example has no error handling. It is important for the client side developer to know if there is a server error. Note, returning 0 rows is not an error.

Comment: Also, by putting the second find in a callback, you have to wait for the first to finish which doubles the time of the request as opposed to running them at the same time.

Comment: True that, but that's not related to the question asked. According to the question, it's about sending data from two queries at once. And also your previous comments still don't explain why you mentioned about **doesn't relying on each other**

Comment: The only reason to have something in a callback is if it relies on the data received from the previous async call

Comment: I got this way to work, but now I can't get the data to load on the page.  When I use the "inspect" page on chrome and check the network tab,  I can see that GET does return one result with two arrays of data.  I'm guessing I have to change my factories.  Do I use one factory to get both sets of data and load them into two different $scope variables?  Or do I use one factory to grab each sets of data separately?

Comment: You can use both options, either way according to this implementation in the server side, you'll have to change the Angular factory.

Comment: I've been trying to get my factory to pull the information and load it into a $scope variable, but I'm not having any luck.  Do you have any recommendations on what  my factory should look like?